# Force npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

I am starting to use node.js and I'm struggling with the following problem:

If the server is not running and have errors, I'm not able to figure out what is happening since my `npm-debug.log` does not tell me anything interesting. Besides, I cannot enter `npm start` because I get errors and I'm stuck in a loop of nonsense.

Is there any command to force the start of the server?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unless you share more about the errors, we cannot say much about it. Please share your code snippet and the error you are facing.

Comment: It's not an error, in general, I would like to do it no matter what error I have.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `package.json` for this in `package.json` you can write following

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node app.js"
},
```

Thanks